# How to fire a new thread to update the DB from Mono?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, java-threads

I have a scenario at which I call an `authentication service` when the user authenticate himself

```
private Mono<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(String id) {
    return restClient
            .post(baseUrl + "/authenticate")
            .body(id)
            .send(AuthenticationResponse.class)
            .doOnSuccess( FIRE_NEW_THREAD )  //Here I need to update the DB  in a new thread 
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error  :: " + e.getMessage(), e));
}
```

After a successful call to the `authentication service` I need to call another component to do a heavy DB update operation, My idea is to fire a new separated thread to do the heavy lifting.
How to fire a new thread safely using the `doOnSuccess` operator

Comment: You dont have to fire a new thread. `doOnSuccess` is async so it will return immediatly and schedule what it needs to on the event loop. As long as what you are doing is not blocking, you dont have to worry.

Comment: Isn't update the DB blocking operation ?

Comment: It all depends on what database and driver you are using. If you are using a R2DBC compatible driver, then no, updating a db is not a blocking operation. A database is not blocking, the driver can be.

Comment: @Toerktumlare doOnSuccess is perform on the subscription thread.

Comment: I have not claimed it being done on any other thread, i wrote its async.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/cs/async-vs-multi-threading